# Locating names with that have 'a' using .filter()

Tags: javascript

So I would like to figure out how to grab all the names from my object that have the letter 'a'. I was able to figure out how to locate a name that starts with the letter 'a'from my .people object, as you can see in the example below. But I want to be able to grab all names that have the letter 'a' anywhere in the name, not just in a specific index position. Thank you! (prefer arrow syntax if possible)

```
const people = [
    {
      Name: 'Ryan',
      Age: 27
    },
    {
      Name: 'Alie',
      Age: 27
    },
    {
      Name: 'Lincoln',
      Age: 4
    },
    {
      Name: 'Luke',
      Age: 2
    },
  ]

const StartsWith = people.filter( letter => letter.Name[0] === 'A' );
console.log(StartsWith)
```

Comment: const contains = people.filter(peep => peep.Name.toLowerCase().split("").includes("a"))

Answer (score 5):

Just use a simple case insensitive regex:

```js
const withA = people.filter(p => /a/i.test(p.Name));
```

Alternatively, convert to lowercase and use [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
const withA = people.filter(p => p.Name.toLowerCase().includes("a"));
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much, I figured there was already a built in way of doing this!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [contains](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_contains.asp)

```
people.filter(person => person.Name.toLowerCase().contains('a'))
```

the `toLowerCase` will make sure you match both 'a' and 'A'

Comment: Nice looks clean and easy! Thanks for the input!